# Windowed WebViews using Awesomium .NET

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, mono, awesomium

How can I use a windowed WebViews on Mac OS X and Linux using Awesomium .NET? If I can't, than how can I use windowless WebViews on Mac OS X and Linux for GUI of my application?